# How can i know the fees of the publication

Tags: journals, fees, elsevier

I need to find the journals that don't take fees for publication in Elsevier. how can I know if the journal I find needs fees or not, please?

Comment: Don't most journals have this mentioned on their website, in their instructions for authors?

Comment: You can probably list your areas or disciplines, and some reader may give you a direct answer.   I.e., which Elsevier journals that publish X do not charge a fee?

Comment: journal like this https://www.journals.elsevier.com/procedia-computer-science how can i know ?

Comment: @Bryan Krause. i mentioned an example and searched a lot for finding "free" word but couldn't find it

Comment: @user550049 On the guide for authors page of that particular journal it says "The author does not have any publication charges for open access. The conference organizers will pay to make the article open access."

Comment: @VitaminE We do not allow a question like that, it would be considered a shopping question.

Answer (score 2):

Check the journal's website, it will invariably say if the journal is fully open access or not. If the journal is not fully open access, then you will probably be able to publish for free. Even if the journal is fully open access, you still might be able to publish for free. The journal's article processing charge is again something you will be able to find from the journal's website.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer... excuse me journal like this https://www.journals.elsevier.com/procedia-computer-science not fully open access i think but how can i make sure please

Comment: @user5520049 go to that webpage and Ctrl + F "In this journal all articles are published Open Access.

Comment: "If the journal is not fully open access, then you will be able to publish for free" - Where are you getting this idea? This is not generally true.

Comment: @BryanKrause that is why I am asking and giving an example to understand .. how can I know if the journal accepts no fees

Comment: @user5520049 That journal mentions fees are paid by the conference organizer on their instructions for authors. Someone else already pointed this out in the comments for that specific journal. You should always find this information on the instructions for authors or similar page on the journal web site.

Comment: @BryanKrause if it's not fully open access, then it is subscription, and there is no article processing charge.

Comment: @Allure That is not true in general. It may be true for some journals.

Comment: @BryanKrause can you give an example?

Comment: @Allure https://us.sagepub.com/en-us/nam/page-and-publication-charges They've become less common in my field as NIH has begun mandating some level of open access, but just a few years ago it was the norm in journals in my field.

Comment: https://journals.asm.org/publication-fees https://www.ametsoc.org/index.cfm/ams/publications/author-information/page-charges-waivers-and-fees/ https://casereports.bmj.com/pages/authors/#cost

Comment: I see what you mean. A hazard of rereading a question months after, I imagine. The answer has already been fixed, too. Thanks.